# Do I need to deactivate driver-side airbag to change the cabin air filter on Peugeot 407?

Tags: peugeot, supplemental-restraint-system, cabin-filter

I have a Peugeot 407. Just below the wheel and above where the pedals are there is a cover with airbag written on it. The cabin air filter is on the right side of the gas pedal based on what I have seen on YouTube.

Should I deactivate the driver-side airbag before I attempt to change the filter? Is it possible at all to do so? I fear for whatever reason while I am meddling with the cabin filter I accidentally set the air bag off while I am close to it.
However, I feel it is not reasonable to be worried about it since the airbag is over the gas pedal and not where the cabin filter is.
But, I feel I need another opinion who knows better.

Answer (score 3):

While I've never dealt with a Peugeot before, manufacturers would not make a vehicle where there is an owner changeable part (ie: cabin air filter) and not account for the airbag. There should be absolutely no fear of the airbag while changing out the filter.

Comment: I agree with Paulster2. Would like to add though that if you decide it's necessary to deactivate the airbags, there are manufacturer specific procedures to follow. If they are not followed, serious injury and expensive repairs are possible.

Comment: Generally disconnecting the battery will deactivate the airbags, but unlikely to be necessary.

Comment: A wait time of 5 minutes after battery disconnect is part of general practice also.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "owner-replaceable".  Steering column controls aren't  hard to change, and on my 406 that meant working very near the airbag connectors.  I recall having to short something (to ground?), but it was 15 years ago.

Comment: @ChrisH - We are talking about a cabin air filter here, not replacing steering column controls. No electronics involved with the CAF.

Comment: I don't expect simple classifications to mean much. Given how hard Peugeot make changing a simple light bulb (legally required for driving), and not having had a filter on my cabin air supply, it wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if you had to disconnect neighbouring wiring to access the filter.  Anyway, the issue with airbags is at least partially static discharge rather than the electrics